# ASP.NET form within a form

Tags: asp.net

I have a .NET project that needs a login form. The action of this form should take the user to the external site (Symplicity) and log them in. I've looked in to some methods (HttpWebRequest and creating a form with javascript), but being fairly new to .net, not sure they will work out for me.

What would be the best way for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

A form cannot be nested within an ASP.NET WebForm. You can use IFrame and within the IFrame you can host your other form.